# Viewing a process's stderr and stdout given a process id

Tags: unix

Is there a tool somewhere that can receive a process id and then start listening to a process's stdout and stderr streams?

Comment: Is strace of no use?

Comment: @RamanSailopal. I didn't know about that - and dtrace for osx. I'd be happy to accept an answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Strace on Linux or dtrace on OSX would be of help to you:

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://linux.die.net/man/1/strace&ved=2ahUKEwim67-Yh5LuAhVGTBoKHV8XALYQFjAAegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw2E15rSRABP4vW0zpJcmkcT